# Finding out if the content of a webview is smaller than the webview itself

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to find out if the content in my webview is smaller than the size of the webview itself.(essentially no vertical scrollbar)

on looking around I found `(webview.getContentHeight()*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density )< webviewheight.getMeasuredHeight())`

But I keep getting 0 for both when I try and log it.

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webview, url);
        Log.i("scrolltest page finished",":"+ mArticleView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled());
        Log.i("heighttest page finished", ":"+( mArticleView.getContentHeight()*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density )+"<"+ mArticleView.getHeight());
    }
```

I always get a true for isVerticalScrollBarEnabled and keep getting Zeros for my heights, what am I doing wrong? is there a simpler way to find out if the content of my webview is smaller than its height?

NOTE:- mArticleView here is a webview.

Comment: Should `mArticleView` be `webview`?

Comment: yes, apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Try changing `mArticleView` to the local `webview` in that method. Just a stab in the dark.

Comment: I have a couple of additional logs with webview, they don't work as well.  I didn't include them just to keep it simple.